# Is there any code editor that works on touch screen mobile phones?

Tags: c#, c, mobile, editor

Is there any code editor (like eclipse or visual studio) that works on mobile phones (such as nokia 5800)?

So what I want is to edit my C/C++/C# code on my phone. (I have Nokia so it is my primary intrest, but I am also interested in other phones such as Android based ones.)

I do not need ability to compile, but I'd love codehinting and code highlighting.

Comment: I'm sure theres a text editor... highly doubt there's an IDE.

Comment: @Fosco: I *very* highly doubt there's a .NET implementation.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: on WM probably there could be one, and no one sad that a compiler can not be on server side - somewere in cloud... But what I need is just code hinting and code highlighting.

Comment: "Just" code hinting? Code hinting pretty much requires a parser, to know what symbols are in scope, what methods exist, that sort of thing. Obviously you can approximate without a fullly-compliant compiler front-end. Try `vi` or `emacs` with a suitable mode...

Comment: Why on earth would you want to write code on a tiny mobile screen? Especially one with an on screen keyboard.

Comment: @Steve Jessop how to install vi onto symbian? or android? I know there are lots of such text editors with code hinting but no compiling options by default  like 'e text editor'...

Comment: @Petey B: with codehinting it can be done quite esely (not always a wirtual keybord is as beeg as all screen)... and It is quite interesting for me in general - to be able to write code on ewery device I have any time I need. I often share my code to my friends and the fastest and defenetly easyest way  for sharing is mobile phone (you do not have notebook with you ewerywhere)

Comment: Erm... not sure about Symbian. Android-wise you could presumably root the phone. Googling, how about this: http://techstroke.com/ymacs-emacs-for-your-firefox-web-browser-edit-your-inside-browser.html. No idea what the state of web browsers on Symbian is, mind you.

Answer (score 7):

There is [touchqode](http://www.touchqode.com/) editor for Android with support of C/C#, but also Java, HTML, JavaScript, Python...

Answer (score 4):

We just release Codeanywhere for Android, try it out I think you guys will like it :)

https://market.android.com/details?id=net.phpanywhere&feature=search_result

Answer (score 3):

For Symbian phones, there's a [Python environment](http://wiki.opensource.nokia.com/projects/PyS60_applications) with several editors existing -- most of them seem geared for Python development, though.

Answer (score 2):

[Emacs for Maemo](http://danielsz.freeshell.org/code/mine/emacs-for-maemo/index.shtml) or [PyGTKEditor for Maemo](http://maemo.org/downloads/product/Maemo5/pygtkeditor/), though I know the Nokia 5800 isn't a Maemo phone.

Comment: and what about Symbian OS?) I mean maemo is cool in ewery way but what about less cool phones?)